# Как получить значение из GET запроса в django view?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть вот такой запрос

```py
path('file/<int:event>', CreateFileView.as_view(), name='add_file') # new
```

Нужно получить `event_id` отсюда во view

View имеет вид:

```py
class CreateFileView(CreateView):
    model = FileFeedbackEventToSubscriber
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'file.html'
    
    success_url = reverse_lazy('filefeedback_events_home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateFileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['current_user'] = self.request.user
        return context
```

Что мне куда или как нужно дописать, чтоб это работало?
Либо есть еще какой-то способ получить значение текущего объекта без запроса сразу из view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.kwargs['event']
```

все просто